# Are these spiders or mites?

Tags: identification, houseplants, pests

I was letting my anthurium soak in a bowl of water and when I took it out noticed these two black tiny spiders in the water.
Are they spider mites or actual spiders? The top of the soil has webbing all over it.[image][image]!

Answer (score 2):

That’s an actual spider! Spider mites live under the leaves and would have webs on the leaves.